# AudioUnit, configure a graph to convert frame and send it to a callback?

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, audiounit

On Mac OS X, I try to get a audio stream from a user selected sound card and do some stuff with PCM buffer coming out.

At this time, I can access to the good device and use a `AudioDeviceIOProc` to get buffer at the hardware native stream description.

Now I want to use a `AUGraph` with my selected device to convert my buffer to a custom ASBD and get it on a `AURenderCallback`.

Here is my setup code `(NSString* deviceUID and AudioStreamBasicDescription streamDescription` are pass in argument to my setup function):

```
        // get the AudioDeviceID
    AudioValueTranslation avt = {&deviceUID,
        sizeof(deviceUID),
        &_inDevice,
        sizeof(_inDevice)};
    UInt32 avt_len = sizeof(avt);
    osstat = AudioHardwareGetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyDeviceForUID, &avt_len, &avt);

    osstat = NewAUGraph(&_inputGraph);

    AudioComponentDescription streamConverterDesc;
    streamConverterDesc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_FormatConverter;
    streamConverterDesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_AUConverter;
    streamConverterDesc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    streamConverterDesc.componentFlags = streamConverterDesc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    AUNode streamConverterNode;
    osstat = AUGraphAddNode(_inputGraph, &streamConverterDesc, &streamConverterNode);

    AudioUnit streamConverterUnit;
    osstat = AUGraphNodeInfo(_inputGraph, streamConverterNode, NULL, &streamConverterUnit);

    osstat = AudioUnitSetProperty(streamConverterUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &streamDescription, sizeof(streamDescription));

    osstat = AudioUnitSetProperty(streamConverterUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &_inDevice, sizeof(_inDevice));

    AudioComponentDescription streamReaderDesc;
    streamReaderDesc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    streamReaderDesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_GenericOutput;
    streamReaderDesc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    streamReaderDesc.componentFlags = streamReaderDesc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

    AUNode streamReaderNode;
    osstat = AUGraphAddNode(_inputGraph, &streamReaderDesc, &streamReaderNode);

    AudioUnit streamReaderUnit;
    osstat = AUGraphNodeInfo(_inputGraph, streamReaderNode, NULL, &streamReaderUnit);

    AURenderCallbackStruct callback;
    callback.inputProc = EIRenderCallback;
    callback.inputProcRefCon = self;
    osstat = AudioUnitSetProperty(streamReaderUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &callback, sizeof(callback));
    osstat = AudioUnitSetProperty(streamReaderUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &streamDescription, sizeof(streamDescription));

    osstat = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(_inputGraph, streamConverterNode, 1, streamReaderNode, 0);

    osstat = AUGraphOpen(_inputGraph);
    osstat = AUGraphInitialize(_inputGraph);
```

And I start my `AUGraph` later.

Actually I got a error -50 on each `AudioUnitSetProperty` with `streamConverterUnit`.

I would like to have a feedback from people used to `CoreAudio`, is this setup flow is good? Why this error -50 and what should I do to finish on a working setup?

Best regards,
Yoann

Answer (score 2):

Try calling AUGraphOpen() before calling AudioUnitSetProperty() for the units in the graph.